# How to make a loading screen on react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I start learning react about 2 month ago. Right now I am trying to build my portfolio with some interactive design using spline 3d. The problem is the loading time is too long and I want to make a loading screen that stop loading exact time when my 3d start element render

Comment: Hi @Htet, you will get more quality help if you can improve the quality of your question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `react-router` actually. Just use some local `isLoading` component state and conditionally render a loading indicator. If you need help further then please edit your post to include a [mcve] for what you've tried so far and provide details on any issues.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I did the same way but that doesn't affect any changes to my page, once the loading screen end my page loading still too long

Comment: Then I'd say you've not implemented it correctly. Please share an actual code example so we can see what the code is doing and why it may not be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I did the below and I'm pretty happy with it. This is for react router v6 with loader functions.

Note that the loading screen will be displayed only while the loader function is being executed. If you want to keep showing it after a route component is rendered and dismiss it from within the component you could pass the `setLoaded` function as a prop to your component in the router configuration.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Outlet,
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';

// Have a function for creating your router so that you can pass
// a function as a prop to your page wrapper, in order for it to let
// you know when a page has loaded
const wireRouter = (setLoaded) => createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <PageWrapper setLoaded={setLoaded} />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/*',
        element: <PageNotFound />,
      },
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: '/pageThatLoadsSomething/',
        element: <PageThatLoadsSomething />,
        loader: () => functionThatLoadsSomething(),
      }
    ]
  }
]);

// In your page wrapper set loaded to true immediately after you render
function PageWrapper({ setLoaded }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return <Outlet />;
}

// Make a root component that keeps state of whether a page is loaded
// and pass the setter to update it to the function that creates your
// router. Render a loader component conditionally, while the page is
// not loaded.
function Root() {
  const [pageLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      { !pageLoaded ? <Loading /> : null }
      <RouterProvider router={wireRouter(setLoaded)} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<Root />);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create it by your self.
you can you use the library `react-loader-spinner`
on the console type `npm install react-loader-spinner --save`

```
import React from 'react';
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import '../style.css';
const LoaderComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="loader">
            <Loader
                type="Circles"
                color="#dc1c2c"
                height={50}
                width={100}
                //timeout={1000} //3 secs
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoaderComponent;
```

To display the component there are multiple ways, here is a way for GraphQL fetching data from the DB

```
const [results] = useQuery({ query: PRODUCT_QUERY });
  const { data, fetching, error } = results;

  //Check or the data coming in
  if (fetching) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  if (error) return <p>Oh no... {error.message}</p>;
```

Here is a way from fetching data with HTTP Request:

```
const UserList = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const [loadedUsers, setLoadedUsers] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        //with fetch, the default request type is GET request
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/users"
        );
        setLoadedUsers(responseData.users); //users propeties is the given value from the backend (user-controllers.js on getUsers())
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [sendRequest]);

  

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
      {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner asOverlay />}
      {/* we need to render loadedUsers only if not empty*/}
      {!isLoading && loadedUsers && (
        <div className="userList">
          <span className="Title">Display Here the data</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  

// this logic is simple 
// first, you have created one boolean usestate(false) and then load your screen that time usestate are true and process is complete after usesate are false
//  I will show you the following example. I hope that helps you.

export default function Gradients(props) {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

   const getAllGradient = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:5000")
      .then((res) => {
        const gradientColors = res.data;
        // process complete after isLoading are false
        // your process (this only example)
         setIsLoading(false);
       })
    
  }
  return(
    <div>
           {
    isLoading ? <Loader> : <YourComponent />
     }
     </div>
    
    )
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```